# Show that the shortest distance between two opposite edges of a regular tetrahedron is equal to half the diagonal of the square described on an edge.

Tags: geometry, vectors, vector-analysis

> Using **vector method**, show that the shortest distance between two opposite edges of a regular tetrahedron is equal to half the diagonal of the square described on an edge.

Let OABC be the tetrahedron, O be the vector origin, and Position vector of A, B, C be $\bar{a}, \bar{b}, \bar{c}$.

Two of its opposite edges are OA and BC whose equations are $\bar{r}=t \bar{a}$ and $\bar{r}=(1-s)\bar{b}+s\bar{c}=\bar{b}+s(\bar{c}-\bar{b})$

Then shortest distance= $$\frac{\{\bar{a}\times(\bar{c}-\bar{b})\}.\bar{b}}{|\bar{a}\times(\bar{c}-\bar{b})|}$$

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: The distance you seek is that between the midpoints of the two edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the sidelength of the tetrahedron by $s$ and the distance between two opposite edges by $h$. We can  assume the vertices as
$$\left(\pm{s\over2},0,-{h\over2}\right),\quad \left(0,\pm{s\over2},{h\over2}\right)$$
and now have to determine $h$ such that the four connecting edges also have length $s$. This gives the condition
$${s^2\over4}+{s^2\over4}+h^2=s^2\ ,\tag{1}$$
from which we immediately obtain ${\displaystyle h={s\over\sqrt{2}}}$.

In vector language this sounds as follows:

Let ${\bf h}$ be a vector connecting the midpoints of two opposite edges, and let ${\bf e}$, ${\bf f}$ be the vectors formed by these two edges. Then the vectors ${\bf h}$, ${\bf e}$, ${\bf f}$ are pairwise orthogonal. It follows that the distance  from any  endpoint of ${\bf e}$ to any endpoint of  ${\bf f}$ is given by
$$\left|{{\bf e}\over2}\right|^2+|{\bf h}|^2+\left|{{\bf f}\over2}\right|^2\ ,$$
so that we obtain the condition $(1)$, as before.